# It keeps saying that the variable mode is being used without being initialized

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studios Express 2013 and it keeps giving me an error saying that the variable mode is being used without being initialized but it is initialized. As you can see I finished everything and I have no idea what I've done wrong. So please I need your help.

This is the code causing the problem

```
            double getMode(int *array, int size)
        {
            int Mode, Most, Count;
            Count = Most = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                Count++;
                if (*(array + i) < *(array + i + 1))
                {
                    if (Count > Most)
                    {
                        Mode = *(array + i);
                        Most = Count;
                    }
                    Count = 0;
                }
            }
            return Mode;
        }
```

## The Whole Program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Function prototype
void getData(int *, int);
void selectionSort(int *, int);
double getAvg(int *, int);
double getMedian(int *, int);
int getMode(int *, int);

int main()
{
    int *Movies, Stud, Mode;
    double Avg, Med;

    // Ask user how many students were surveyed.
    cout << "How many students were surveyed? ";
    cin >> Stud;

    Movies = new int[Stud];

    getData(Movies, Stud);

    selectionSort(Movies, Stud);

    Avg = getAvg(Movies, Stud);

    Med = getMedian(Movies, Stud);

    Mode = getMode(Movies, Stud);

    cout << "Statistical results for the number of movies\n"
        << "     college students see in a month.\n";
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Average: " << Avg << endl;
    cout << "Median:  " << Med << endl;
    cout << "Mode:    " << Mode << endl;

    delete[] Movies;
    Movies = 0;

    return 0;
}

//*******************************************************************************
//                                  getData                                     *
// The function asks the user to enter the survey data and stores it in an      *
// integer array. The size parameter holds the size of the array.               *
//*******************************************************************************
void getData(int *array, int size)
{
    cout << "Enter the number of movies each student has seen in the month.\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Student " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> *(array + i);
    }
}

//*******************************************************************************
//                                    selectionSort                             *
// This function performs an ascending-order selection sort on array. The       *
// parameter size holds the number of elements in the array.                    *
//*******************************************************************************
void selectionSort(int *array, int size)
{
    int scan, minIndex, minValue;

    for (int scan = 0; scan < (size - 1); scan++)
    {
        minIndex = scan;
        minValue = *(array + scan);
        for (int i = scan + 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (*(array + i) < minValue)
            {
                minValue = *(array + i);
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
        *(array + minIndex) = *(array + scan);
        *(array + scan) = minValue;
    }
}

//*******************************************************************************
//                                  getAvg                                      *
// This function calculates and returns the average of the values in array. The *
// parameter size holds the number of elements in array.                        * 
//*******************************************************************************
double getAvg(int *array, int size)
{
    double Sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Sum += *(array + i);
    }
    return Sum / size;
}

//*******************************************************************************
//                                 getMedian                                    *
// This function calculates and returns the median of the values in the array.  *
// The parameter size holds the number of elements in the array.                *
//*******************************************************************************
double getMedian(int *array, int size)
{
    int Mid = (size - 1) / 2;
    double Med;

    if (size % 2 == 0)
    {
        Med = (*(array + Mid) + *(array + (Mid + 1))) / 2;
    }
    else
        Med = *(array + Mid);

    return Med;
}

//*******************************************************************************
//                                  getMode                                     *
// This function calculates and returns the mode of the values in the array.    *
// The parameter size holds the number of elements in the array.                *
//*******************************************************************************
int getMode(int *array, int size)
{
    int Mode, Most, Count;
    Count = Most = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Count++;
        if (*(array + i) < *(array + i + 1))
        {
            if (Count > Most)
            {
                Mode = *(array + i);
                Most = Count;
            }
            Count = 0;
        }
    }
    return Mode;
}
```

Comment: In the function `getMode`, what happens if `size` is zero or less?

Comment: Your `getMode` function may not set `Mode` to anything under some circumstances.

Comment: Also you'll read one past the end of the array on this line: `if (*(array + i) < *(array + i + 1))`. What if i == (size - 1)?

Comment: Another case where you don't set Mode in getMode: What if every value in the array is the same?

Comment: Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow, but [please read about how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it might explain why the question is being downvoted. For instance, there are two distinct variables called `mode` but you didn't tell us it was the one much further down the page that was the problem, nor quote the exact error message.

Comment: Sorry about not being specific enough, I'm still new to programming and asking for help about it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a breakpoint on that function. You can see that in `if (*(array + i) < *(array + i + 1))` sometimes it returns `false` value that's why Mode is not initialized.

Comment: When I make the breakpoint at if (*(array + i) < *(array + i + 1)) the program just stops there and won't continue

Comment: Put the breakpoint in the for then press F10 to show the flow of the process.